# Checking if values in multiple fields are null relative to each other?

Tags: python, pandas, eval

So I am using the eval function to perform operations on various fields. I wish to continue using eval. Consider the expression
`result = fieldA + feildB`  My problem is however that if there is a null values in one of the fields, eval returns null instead of treating it as a 0 in the case of an addition formula. My current outputted table looks as follows:

| fieldA | fieldB | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |
| null | 5 | null |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 0 | 6 | 6 |

I want to evaluate if one of the values(not both) is null to then fillna(0). If both are null I would like both fields to stay null. My desired outputted table should look like this:

| fieldA | fieldB | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |
| 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 0 | 6 | 6 |

I am pretty lost as to where to begin with such a conditional so any help would be really appreciated. I could always butcher this with loops but I am always very relucent to go down that path with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) you would need to use [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) and the `fill_value=0` parameter:

```
df['result'] = df['fieldA'].add(df['fieldB'], fill_value=0)
```

You can use the same syntax with `eval`:

```
out = df.eval('result = fieldA.add(fieldB, fill_value=0)')
```

Alternatively:

```
out = df.eval('result = fieldA.fillna(0) + fieldB.fillna(0)')
```

Output:

```
   fieldA  fieldB  result
0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1     NaN     5.0     5.0
2     4.0     5.0     9.0
3     0.0     6.0     6.0
```

Reproducible input:

```
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'fieldA': [nan, nan, 4.0, 0.0],
                   'fieldB': [nan, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not easy to do with `pd.eval`.Why don't you use "standard" Pandas ?

```
cols = ['fieldA', 'fieldB']
m = df[cols].notna().any(axis=1)

out = (df.loc[m, cols].fillna(0)
         .assign(result=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
         .reindex(df.index))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   fieldA  fieldB  result
0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1     0.0     5.0     5.0
2     4.0     5.0     9.0
3     0.0     6.0     6.0
```